# Remover auto identação do Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

boa tarde, estou usando o Visual Studio há pouco tempo (por mudanças na empresa) e quero que ele pare de ficar "ajeitando" o código automaticamente, fiz um gif tentando exemplificar (a versão que e estou usando é a Community 2019)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu não quero que a chave suba novamente quando eu pressiono enter, tampouco que ele junte os espaços entre parenteses e etc. Tentei procurar nas opções do Editor mas não teve jeito, alguém consegue me ajudar com isso por favor?

Adicionado abaixo print das opções citadas nas respostas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Vá em Tools ou Ferramentas, dependendo do idioma do seu VS, options/opções, vai abrir a janela de configuração, nela navegue neste caminho:

Text Editor -> C# -> Formatting -> General , e desmarque os 3 checkbox,

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: MUITOOOOOOOOOO OBRIGADO, procurava essa opção fazia muito tempo, funcionou 100%

Answer (score 0):

Veja em ARQUIVO > PREFERÊNCIA > CONFIGURAÇÕES > EDITOR DE TEXTO e desmarca AUTO INDENT.

Comment: Olá Vitor, obrigado pela resposta mas não tem essa opção lá (adicionei na pergunta print da janela)